# How to add a button to each row in mat-table Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular9

Following the example in this link. I am able to make a expandable table. (Made some changes so it will fit to Angular 9).

Now I added a actions col so that I can have attach a button to each row. But it is does not seems to work. It is only showing an empty action col.

Help Me Please !

```
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
       class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <div class="example-element-diagram">
          <div class="example-element-position"> {{element.position}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-symbol"> {{element.symbol}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-name"> {{element.name}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-weight"> {{element.weight}} </div>
        </div>
        <div class="example-element-description">
          {{element.description}}
          <span class="example-element-description-attribution"> -- Wikipedia </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <mat-header-cell > Actions </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" >
     <button mat-button >Edit</button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

[Angular 13 code example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-expandable-rows)

Comment: In where do you want to add button?

Comment: I added a new col and I want the button to sit inside each new cell

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `actions` to columns attribute in last tr tag to define columns.

`columns: ['expandedDetail','actions']"`

Comment: this error will pop up `Error, can not find column with id [name, weight, symbol, position ]`

Comment: BTW I used `columns: [expandedDetail,'actions']"`

Comment: @TonyLi yeah, I checked it again and didn't worked. so you can use `Table with selection` mat-table example and just instead check-box use button for your purpose. https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-selection